# What does it mean to instantiate an object using X.new Y()?

Tags: java, class

So I am looking at some examples of networking code and I can't figure out what this does. I'm assuming that it creates a new variable in the given class but I cannot seem to do that myself. Could someone explain to me what it does?

The actual line is:

```
Game.Player playerX = game.new Player(listener.accept(), 'X');
```

`Game` is another class in the program and `Player` is a thread class. I am wondering what `Game.Player playerX` and `game.new Player` does. I will paste the rest of relevant code below.

Main class:

```
public class TicTacToeServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(8901);
        System.out.println("Tic Tac Toe Server is Running");
        try {
            while (true) {
                Game game = new Game();
                Game.Player playerX = game.new Player(listener.accept(), 'X');
                Game.Player playerO = game.new Player(listener.accept(), 'O');
                playerX.setOpponent(playerO);
                playerO.setOpponent(playerX);
                game.currentPlayer = playerX;
                playerX.start();
                playerO.start();
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Game class:

```
class Game {

    private Player[] board = {
        null, null, null,
        null, null, null,
        null, null, null};

    Player currentPlayer;

    public boolean hasWinner() {
        return
            (board[0] != null && board[0] == board[1] && board[0] == board[2])
          ||(board[3] != null && board[3] == board[4] && board[3] == board[5])
          ||(board[6] != null && board[6] == board[7] && board[6] == board[8])
          ||(board[0] != null && board[0] == board[3] && board[0] == board[6])
          ||(board[1] != null && board[1] == board[4] && board[1] == board[7])
          ||(board[2] != null && board[2] == board[5] && board[2] == board[8])
          ||(board[0] != null && board[0] == board[4] && board[0] == board[8])
          ||(board[2] != null && board[2] == board[4] && board[2] == board[6]);
    }

    public boolean boardFilledUp() {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            if (board[i] == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public synchronized boolean legalMove(int location, Player player) {
        if (player == currentPlayer && board[location] == null) {
            board[location] = currentPlayer;
            currentPlayer = currentPlayer.opponent;
            currentPlayer.otherPlayerMoved(location);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    class Player extends Thread {
            char mark;
            Player opponent;
            Socket socket;
            BufferedReader input;
            PrintWriter output;

            public Player(Socket socket, char mark) {
                this.socket = socket;
                this.mark = mark;
                try {
                    input = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    output.println("WELCOME " + mark);
                    output.println("MESSAGE Waiting for opponent to connect");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Player died: " + e);
                }
            }

            public void setOpponent(Player opponent) {
                this.opponent = opponent;
            }

            public void otherPlayerMoved(int location) {
                output.println("OPPONENT_MOVED " + location);
                output.println(
                    hasWinner() ? "DEFEAT" : boardFilledUp() ? "TIE" : "");
            }

            public void run() {
                try {
                    output.println("MESSAGE All players connected");

                    if (mark == 'X') {
                        output.println("MESSAGE Your move");
                    }

                    while (true) {
                        String command = input.readLine();
                        if (command.startsWith("MOVE")) {
                            int location = Integer.parseInt(command.substring(5));
                            if (legalMove(location, this)) {
                                output.println("VALID_MOVE");
                                output.println(hasWinner() ? "VICTORY"
                                             : boardFilledUp() ? "TIE"
                                             : "");
                            } else {
                                output.println("MESSAGE ?");
                            }
                        } else if (command.startsWith("QUIT")) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Player died: " + e);
                } finally {
                    try {socket.close();} catch (IOException e) {}
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Also: why is `Game` not `public` or `private`? It is just `class`.

Comment: Check out inner classes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis does the line in question declare a new variable in the instance of the class Game?

Comment: No. It creates a `Game.Player` instance associated with the object `game`. (Incidentally, `Player` must be nested inside the `Game` class. I think you broke that.)

Comment: @user2263904: see my edit. Notice how `Player` is actually a part of the `Game` class.

Comment: Ohh I see now! thanks. Also why is Game not public or private? @user2357112

Answer (score 2):

You're instantiating an [inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html). Basically this is a class contained inside another class. In order to instantiate such a class, you first need an instance of the outer class (in your case `Game`).

It should be noted that usually you don't want this: inner classes are meant to provide an extra sense of encapsulation within the outer class. It is made an inner class for a reason: the contents should be contained within that outer class. By still exposing it to the (partial) outside world, this intent is sort of defeated. For this reason inner classes are usually `private`.

Constructor for the outer class:

```
Game game = new Game();
```

Constructor for the inner class, using the outer class' instance:

```
Game.Player playerX = game.new Player(listener.accept(), 'X');
```

> Also: why is Game not public or private? It is just class.

Why? I don't know why exactly they did it like that in this particular case, but it is definitely possible. Making a class `private` doesn't make much sense, unless it's an inner class. If it isn't, it can't be accessed from anywhere anyway.

Have a look at [the access modifiers table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notice that it's not Game.new but game.new

When an object is defined inside another object it needs an instance of the parent object around in order to be instantiated (It can access member info from the parent class instance).

Usually the child is "Newed" from within an instance of the parent class so it's no problem, this obscure, annoying and bizarre syntax is helping you do that outside the parent class.

Also you are going to have problems doing it yourself--when a class like "Player" doesn't have a public/private designation that makes it "Package private" which means it's public to anything in it's own package, private to all others.

Comment: to add: static inner classes can be called without an instance of the parent class.